# Angular factory method is not a function (dataFactory.addContact is not a function)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

Im trying to split controllers and factories into separate files. However when separate the factory methods generate an error: "dataFactory.addContact is not a function"... Im sure i've missed something fundamental.

//The Error

```
TypeError: dataFactory.addContact is not a function
at Scope.$scope.AddContactToDb (http://localhost:3000/assets/js/controllers/contacts/main.js:28:15)
at Scope.$scope.AddContact (http://localhost:3000/assets/js/controllers/contacts/main.js:56:25)
at fn (eval at <anonymous> (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.js:13391:15), <anonymous>:2:229)
at ngEventDirectives.(anonymous function).compile.element.on.callback (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.js:23619:17)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.js:16058:28)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.js:16158:25)
at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.js:23624:23)
at HTMLInputElement.eventHandler (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.js:3299:21)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12546$get @ angular.js:9307$get.Scope.$apply @ angular.js:16163(anonymous function) @ angular.js:23624eventHandler @ angular.js:3299
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12546
$get @ angular.js:9307
$get.Scope.$apply @ angular.js:16163
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:23624
eventHandler @ angular.js:3299
```

Here is my code:

//datafactory.js

```
app.factory('dataFactory', ['$http', function ($http){

    var dataFactory = {

        getContactList: function(){
            return $http.get("/api/contacts"); 
        },
        addContact: function(newContact){
            return $http.post("/api/contacts", newContact);  
        }

    };


    return dataFactory;
}]);
```

//controller.js

```
app.controller('contactlist', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', 'dataFactory', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, dataFactory){

    //get contact list
    dataFactory.getContactList().success(function(response){ //<< works
        $scope.contacts = response;
    });
    //add contact to db 
    $scope.AddContactToDb = function(newContact){

        dataFactory.addContact(newContact).success(function(){ //<< fails (dataFactory.addContact is not a function)

            $scope.Status = "New contact: '" + newContact.name + "' was successfully inserted.";

        }).error(function(error){

            console.log(error);

        });
    };

//add contact
$scope.AddContact = function(){

    if($scope.contactform.$valid) {

        var newContact = 
        {
            name : $scope.Contact.Name,
            email : $scope.Contact.Email,
            number : $scope.Contact.Number
        };

        $scope.contacts.push(newContact);

        var success = $scope.AddContactToDb(newContact);

        if(success){
            resetForm();
        }

    } else {

        return;

    }
};
}]);
```

Comment: Hard to see why...code seems clean. Are you sure that the code being served is same as what you are showing? Double check in browser

Comment: could you add plunkr with reproducible issue, that would be more better..

Comment: Yes its all served correctly, the "get" method fires successfully and 'gets' the contact list. Im baffled why the "post" method fails.

Comment: @learningAngularIsFrustrating does post method fails, or the service method fails to call from controller? both calls just got work here http://plnkr.co/edit/otkSTmOjD29qLfkyvuFU?p=preview

Comment: Hi Pankaj Parkar, the  dataFactory.getContactList() method fires successfully though, the other doesnt.

Comment: I've updated the original post with the error stack.

Comment: There must be something else going on. Do you have another `dataFactory` defined?

Comment: Is that all that's there in the datafactory ? If there some other code trying to access the addContact within the factory can also cause this problem ..

Comment: There could be several reasons depending on what server side language you are using. Easiest thing to try is setting the headers in your post to format the data: 

$http({
       withCredentials: false,
       method: 'post',
       url: "/api/contacts", 
       headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
       data: newContact
 });

Comment: No other methods in the application access the addContact method and thats the complete code of the datafactory.js file. Do note that if I move the "dataFactory" factory into controller.js file, both dataFactory methods work, which i find strange...
Its a mean app therefore sits within an express app

Answer (score 1):

I do see there are 2 methods with name addContact. The difference is case sensitivity. Please call the method "AddContact" instead of "addContact".

Hope this works.

Comment: I don't think that will work... the "datafactory.js" represents the node api, however the "controller.js" is an actual angular controller. My apologies if it appears a lil misleading.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//with factory
angular.module('app.services', [])

.factory('LoginFactory', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        getConnexion: function(newData) {
            var url = "http://localhost:9100/connexion";
            return $http.post(url, newData);
        }
    }
}])

//in controller
angular.module('app.controllers', [])

.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'LoginFactory', '$ionicPopup', '$state', '$http',
    function($scope, $stateParams, LoginFactory, $ionicPopup, $state, $http) {
        function checkEmail(email) {
            var re = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
            return re.test(email);
        }
        $scope.connexion = function() {
            if (typeof this.email !== "undefined" && typeof this.password !== "undefined") {
                if (true === checkEmail(this.email)) {
                    var Objetdata = {
                        email: this.email,
                        password: this.password
                    };
                    LoginFactory.getConnexion(Objetdata).success(function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    }).error(function(error) {
                        $ionicPopup.alert({
                            title: 'Error',
                            template: error
                        });
                    });
                    //console.log($scope.items);
                    //$state.go('menu.profil', {});
                } else {
                    $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title: 'Error',
                        template: 'E-mail is not Valide !'
                    });
                }
            } else {
                $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: 'Error',
                    template: 'E-mail or Password is Empty !'
                });
            }
        };
    }
])
```